# Laravel Livewire File Upload does not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have created a livewire component Avatar with the contents:

```
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class Avatar extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    /**
     * @var \Livewire\TemporaryUploadedFile
     */
    public $photo;

    public function updated()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'photo' => [
                'image',
                'max:4096',
            ],
        ]);
        $file = $this->photo->store('upload');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.profile.avatar');
    }
}
```

Here's the view:

```
<div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form>
                <input type="file" accept="image/*" wire:model="photo">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure what I am missing but this is not uploading to my public directory in my Laravel app. Anyone can give me some help? Thanks!

Comment: The folder will be uploaded to `/storage/app/uploads/`. You can specify a symlink in `config/filesystem.php`

Comment: Thank you very much on this info. I am very new to Laravel and I am still exploring the framework. Again, thank you for giving me this info.

Comment: No problem. Also, you should add some error-handling in your view, so that if the validation fails, the user is notified. Its also nice if you inform them that the upload was successful.

Answer (score 2):

The folder will be uploaded to /storage/app/uploads/. You can specify a symlink in config/filesystem.php

---

note- copied verbatim from a comment by [Qirel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4535200/qirel) on the original question - but it seems that this should be an answer and not a comment. So I'm posting this as Community Wiki.